# Drupal 7: Display latest articles by an author with bio

Tags: nodes, panels, views, chaos-tool-suite

I have a content type called "Author" and have an author field on other content types which has a reference to the "Author" CT. (e.g. News Article having an author field)

The "Author" CT has these fields:

- Title (Author Name)
- Image
- Bio

I'm using Panels on Drupal to create pages and I want to display Author pages like /author/author-name with Views, Panels, etc to display the Author name as Title of the page, author image and bio on top and the latest nodes by that author below all that bio.

I've created a view called Author with a contextual filter Content: Author but I'm unsure about how to use this on a Panel.

How do I go around this process to embrace panel pages and views to create author pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here's what I did.

I created a panel page with a selection rule as **Node Type = Author**.

I changed the URL pattern (pathauto) for Author content type as **author/[node:title]**

Then I created a view with a content pane called *Author Archives* with a Contextual Filter set to **Content: Author** and set the option *WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE* to **Provide default value: Content ID from URL**. This view then looks for the author ID in the URL and then displays all the content posted by that Author.

I then dropped that view pane on the panel page that I created before with other page elements like *node being viewed: Title* for Page title as Author name, *node being viewed: Image* as the author image and *node being viewed: Body* as the Author Bio.

After saving this panel, when you go to any author node (/author/author-name) -- you'll see an author archive with Author name, image, bio and all the latest articles from the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a views panel pane (available as a views display mode) and place that with panels, then you can accept arguments from the panels context when editing the view. The display will have panels argument options controls that other display modes do not offer.

Comment: I understand that I can just drop the view pane in a panel but if a node (like News article) has a an author field displayed on the node (e.g. This news article is by "Author Name") and if someone clicks on that "Author Name" link to open the author node, how will it be displayed? I want to have that author node to display that panel page I create. And how do I add the bio and image on that panel? I mean, which view?

Comment: This sounds like several different questions.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Ok, I've figured something out now. I created a panel variant with a selection rule as node type being viewed (=author) and the URL pattern for an author is /author/author-name so when I open an author node it picks up that panel variant. I've then created a view displaying all nodes (except author nodes) with a contextual filter Content: Author so that I can display all the articles from an author.  Now my only question is this: When I drop this view on that panel variant then the articles are not displayed on /author/author-name. Is the contextual filter correct?

Comment: OK, I've figured it out. The contextual filter is Content: Author only but with "Provide default value" set to "Content ID from URL". *feels stupid*. Thanks for your help, Beth. :)